# Mongoose schema inheritance and model populate

Tags: node.js, inheritance, mongoose, populate

I have been trying this with the built in inheritance features of mongoose (rather than the extend plugin) but haven't been having much luck so far. This is a simplified example of code I am trying to use which exhibits the same problem. This is based on an expanded version of the mongoose documentation for schema inheritance using discriminators - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.discriminator

```
var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/problem');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

function BaseSchema() {
  Schema.apply(this, arguments);

  this.add({
    name: String,
    createdAt: Date
  });
}
util.inherits(BaseSchema, Schema);


var BossStatusSchema = new Schema({
  status: String
});
var BossStatus = mongoose.model('BossStatus', BossStatusSchema);

var PersonSchema = new BaseSchema();
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

var BossSchema = new BaseSchema({
  department: String,
  bossStatus: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'BossStatus'
  }
});
var Boss = Person.discriminator('Boss', BossSchema);
```

Example code to add the documents:

```
var superBoss = new BossStatus({
  status: 'super'
});
var normalBoss = new BossStatus({
  status: 'normal'
});
var andy = new Person({
  name: 'Andy'
});
var billy = new Boss({
  name: 'Billy',
  bossStatus: superBoss._id
});

var callback = function(err, result) {
  console.dir(err);
  console.dir(result);
};

superBoss.save(callback);
normalBoss.save(callback);
andy.save(callback);
billy.save(callback);
```

So when finding a record **without** populate:

```
Person
.findOne({
  name: 'Billy'
})
.exec(callback);
```

The result is as expected, the bossStatus refers to an _id from the bossstatuses collection:

```
null
{ name: 'Billy',
  bossStatus: 52a20ab0185a7f4530000001,
  _id: 52a20ab0185a7f4530000004,
  __v: 0,
  __t: 'Boss' }
```

When adding the populate call:

```
Person
.findOne({
  name: 'Billy'
})
.populate('bossStatus')
.exec(callback);
```

The resulting bossStatus property of the Person result is **null**:

```
null
{ name: 'Billy',
  bossStatus: null,
  _id: 52a20ab0185a7f4530000004,
  __v: 0,
  __t: 'Boss' }
```

EDIT:

Ok I've just put together what is probably a better example of what I'm trying to achieve, the schema structure lends itself more to a relational DB but hopefully makes the problem clearer.

```
var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/problem');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

function BaseSchema() {
  Schema.apply(this, arguments);

  this.add({
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true
    }
  });
}
util.inherits(BaseSchema, Schema);

var DeviceSchema = new BaseSchema();
var LocalDeviceSchema = new BaseSchema({
  driver: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Driver'
  }
});
var RemoteDeviceSchema = new BaseSchema({
  networkAddress: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'NetworkAddress'
  }
});

var DriverSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  }
});

var NetworkHostSchema = new Schema({
  host: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  }
});

var NetworkAddressSchema = new Schema({
  networkHost: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'NetworkHost'
  },
  port: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1,
    max: 65535
  }
});

var Driver = mongoose.model('Driver', DriverSchema);
var NetworkHost = mongoose.model('NetworkHost', NetworkHostSchema);
var NetworkAddress = mongoose.model('NetworkAddress', NetworkAddressSchema);

var Device = mongoose.model('Device', DeviceSchema);
var LocalDevice = Device.discriminator('LocalDevice', LocalDeviceSchema);
var RemoteDevice = Device.discriminator('RemoteDevice', RemoteDeviceSchema);

var networkHost = new NetworkHost({
  host: '192.168.2.1'
});

var networkAddress = new NetworkAddress({
  networkHost: networkHost._id,
  port: 3000
});

var remoteDevice = new RemoteDevice({
  name: 'myRemoteDevice',
  networkAddress: networkAddress._id
});


var driver = new Driver({
  name: 'ftdi'
});

var localDevice = new LocalDevice({
  name: 'myLocalDevice',
  driver: driver._id
});


var callback = function(err, result) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.dir(result);
};

/*
// Uncomment to save documents

networkHost.save(function() {
  networkAddress.save(function() {
    remoteDevice.save(callback);
  });
});

driver.save(function() {
  localDevice.save(callback);
});
*/

var deviceCallback = function(err, device) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  switch(device.__t) {
    case 'LocalDevice':
      console.log('Would create a local device instance passing populated result');
      break;
    case 'RemoteDevice':
      console.log('Would create a remote device instance passing populated result');
      break;
  }
};

Device
.findOne({name: 'myLocalDevice'})
.populate('driver')
.exec(deviceCallback);
```

The LocalDevice and RemoteDevice schemas could (and probably would) include other differences..
The switch would for example use a DeviceFactory or something to create the instances. My thinking was it should be possible to search the devices table for a device by 'name' and populate the collection references (if this is the correct terminology?) without having to specify the collection to search in - this was my understanding of the point of schema inheritance - or have I completely misunderstood?

Thanks for replies so far!

Comment: Did either of these answers solve your problem? Did you find another solution?

Comment: They didn't solve the problem unfortunately, it still seems like a shortcoming of mongoose - perhaps it will be addressed in future releases. I haven't found another solution but haven't really looked at it since.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a Boss, not a Person:

```
Boss
.findOne({
  name: 'Billy'
})
.populate('bossStatus')
.exec(callback);
```

Comment: I was actually running them separately so I would first do the saving/adding of the documents to the collections. Then later, commenting out the saves and uncommenting the find query. I tried your suggestion just in case but the result is still null.

I found another similar issue on here where the OP was using the schema-extend plugin but not sure how this can be applied to this example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218080/populate-with-inherited-document-in-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

<s>Looks like a bug. With debugging active, this is what's being shown for the population query:</s>

```
Mongoose: people.findOne({ name: 'Billy' }) { fields: undefined }
Mongoose: people.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("52a221ee639cc03d71000001") ] } }) { fields: undefined }
```

(the `ObjectId` shown is the one stored in `bossStatus`)

So Mongoose is querying the wrong collection (`people` instead of `bossstatuses`).

As @regretoverflow pointed out, if you're looking for a boss, use the `Boss` model and not the `Person` model.

If you do want to populate `bossStatus` through the `Person` model, you can explicitly state a model that needs to be searched for population:

```
.populate({
  path  : 'bossStatus',
  model : 'BossStatus'
})
// or shorter but less clear:
// .populate('bossStatus', {}, 'BossStatus')
```

**EDIT:** (with your `Device` examples)

`driver` is part of `LocalDeviceSchema`, but you're querying the `Device` model, which has no notion of what `driver` is and populating `driver` within the context of a `Device` instance doesn't make sense to Mongoose.

Another possibility for populating each instance is to do it after you retrieved the document. You already have the `deviceCallback` function, and this will probably work:

```
var deviceCallback = function(err, device) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  switch(device.__t) { // or `device.constructor.modelName`
    case 'LocalDevice':
      device.populate('driver', ...);
      break;
    case 'RemoteDevice':
      device.populate('networkAddress', ...);
      break;
  }
};
```

The reason is that the document is already cast into the correct model there, something that apparently doesn't happen when you chain `populate` with the `find`.

Comment: He needs to look for a Boss, not a Person -

Comment: @regretoverflow uh you're right! I'll edit my answer and leave some parts of it in, perhaps it's useful for finding bosses through the `Person` model :)

Comment: Put together an updated example above, not sure if I'm misunderstanding this.. Thanks for the help so far though

Comment: Thanks @robertklep, I see what you mean. I had tried adding a 'DeviceAttributes' collection which held the differences between the devices and kept the 'Device' Model consistent e.g.

    driver = new Driver({
      name: 'ftdi'
    });
    localDeviceAttributes = new DeviceAttributes({attributes: driver._id});
    localDevice = new LocalDevice({
      name: 'myLocalDevice',
      deviceAttributes: localDeviceAttributes._id
    });

I've just written that off the top of my head so hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: The deviceAttributes would be declared in the BaseSchema so in theory should work based on what I've understood of your update - which is what made me feel like this is kind of a mongoose bug, but maybe just that the populate is a bit restrictive in this scenario..